# How to stop shadow effect from moving using pure css?

Tags: html, css

I have a hover effect on an image, in which 'floats' upwards on hover.

However, I've been trying to implement it in such a way that the shadow remains static during this hover effect (i.e. make the image look like it's hovering off the ground.

So far my jsfiddle looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jtf4eqpo/).

It's using the

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
```

in order to generate the shadow.

So, the image should look like (when unhovered):

```
+------+
|      |
|      |
+------+
________     <-- shadow/hover
```

---

```
                                                 /\
Hovered:                                        /||\
                                                 ||
                                                 ||
+------+                                         ||
|      |                                     floor level
|      |                                         ||
+------+                                         ||
                                                \||/
 ______      <-- shadow/hover                    \/
```

---

```
   ^
   |
```

the shadow should also 'shink' in size (but that shouldn't be *too* bad to implement.

So the 'shadow' shouldn't move, and the img should raise.

```css
.threeWidget {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: AppWorkspace;
  margin: 2px;
}
.topMenImg {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.topMenImg:hover {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.TopMenu {
  background-color: #808080;
  border-style: inset solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.topMenImg:hover::after {
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
}
.topMenImg::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="topMenImg" style="float:left ;margin-left:8%">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/1/8/b/1264830175321493735blue-marble-globe-md.png" />
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

As you can tell, i'm not css genius, but I have dreams :)

**Edit**

Something like the [Floating shadow shown here](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) is what i'm looking/aiming for

Comment: maybe you could add the shadow to the div and only animate the image within the div

Comment: Have you tried just placing the shadow effect in an element below the globe?

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom - i've tried that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jtf4eqpo/7/). Doesn't *fully* work

Comment: It works, only the shadow is always showing, that is something you should be able to fix yourself, but I think the initial question is answered right?

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom *the shadow should also 'shink' in size* - but as the nice shadow in the question compares with this 'rectangle, i'm not quite there yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type="text"], input[type="button"], .search{
border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
-webkit-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
padding-left:2px;
}

input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 5px 1px rgba(16, 216, 252, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 5px 1px rgba(16, 216, 252, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 5px 1px rgba(16, 216, 252, 0.8);
}



.TopMenu{
    width:100%;
   background-color:darkgray;

   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 131px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 131px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 131px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);

float:left;
border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
-webkit-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}

.search {
margin-right:2%;
width:auto;
margin-left:0;
display:flexbox;
margin:auto;
}
.searchTextBox{
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
.searchButtonSubmit{
    width:auto;
    margin-right:1%;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.topMenuImg{
    margin-left:5%;
    float:left;
    transition: 0.2s;
    position: relative;
    display:table-cell;
    z-index:10;
}

.topMenuImg:first-child{
    margin-left:20%;
}

.topMenuImg:hover{
     -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.topMenuImg:after{ /*This is the shadow effect*/
        content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1%;
    left: 3%;
    z-index:0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 8%;

    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.10);
        transition: 0.2s;
         -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.80);
}
    
.topMenuImg:hover:after{ /*Also shadow effect*/
          content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index:0;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 18%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 8%;
    border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.40);
  transform: scale(0.2);

    -moz-transform: translate(0, 4px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 4px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 4px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 4px);
    transform: translate(0, 4px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);

}
```

```html
  <div id="TopMenu" class="">
                        <div class="topMenuImg"><img src="~/Content/Images/TopMenu/Add.png" /></div>
                        <div class="topMenuImg"><img src="~/Content/Images/TopMenu/Delete.png" /></div>
                        <div class="topMenuImg"><img src="~/Content/Images/TopMenu/Edit.png" /></div>
                        <div class="topMenuImg"><img src="~/Content/Images/TopMenu/Save.png" /></div>
                        <div class="topMenuImg"><img src="~/Content/Images/TopMenu/Print.png" /></div>
                        <div class="topMenuImg"><img src="~/Content/Images/TopMenu/Search.png" /></div>
                    </div>
```

I managed to edit my css (quite a bit) of fiddling with a LOT of the values, finally coming up with this:

In terms of the example fiddle, I have altered it to become [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jtf4eqpo/15/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtf4eqpo/12/)**

I added a new child div and added the box-shadow to that, and then set a hover state on the parent that activated the child.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="topMenImg" style="float:left ;margin-left:8%">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/1/8/b/1264830175321493735blue-marble-globe-md.png" />
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.topMenImg img {
    transition:0.5s;
}
.topMenImg:hover {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
    transform: translate(0, -8px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.topMenImg:hover::after {
    content:"";
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.shadow {
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
}

.topMenImg:hover .shadow {
    transform: scaleX(.8);
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: It's good so far in terms of a basis - will just check it out a bit to see if it suits. but thanks :)

Comment: @jbutler483 Hope it is useful for you; of course feel free to adjust the timing and scaling amounts or the distance of the shadow from the globe image, as needed :-)

Comment: just trying to make it dynamic at the mo cause i've to make a (relatively) responsive design - for different sized images/etc

Comment: I don't suppose you know a way of stopping the shadow from moving vertically?

Comment: @jbutler483 The closest you can come without resorting to JS or completely revamping your code is to change `transform: scaleX(.8);` to `transform: scaleX(.8) translateY(1px);` This may sometimes let you see it move up and then back down, but there's no way to animate only one property of a `transform` that includes multiple properties, as far as I know.

Comment: @jbutler483 But I hear that such a feature *is* being worked on for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

give your image an id:

```
<div class="topMenImg" style="float:left ;margin-left:8%">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/1/8/b/1264830175321493735blue-marble-globe-md.png" />
</div>
```

Then add the hover to your id:

```
#image:hover {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -8px);
  transform: translate(0, -8px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

And give your div with the class: `topMenImg` the shadow

Comment: JSFiddle proof, please.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the shadow's y offset by the same amount that you decrease the button's y offset.