# Flyout effect on image

Tags: jquery, css

here is the link
http://t3n.de/news/billig-rechner-intel-compute-stick-587589/

On left-side bottom-line of this page,there is a image like envelope. When you do hover on this image,the image is flyout. I am not sure what is called this effect? Actually i need this effect in project. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](http://james-star.com/answers/en/css3-hover-effect-transitions-transformations-and-animations/) - which doesn't need to use jquery - just pure css!

But below is a simple example of what i *think* you're looking to achieve:

```css
img{
  margin-top:50px; /*for demo purposes*/
  margin-left:50px; /*for demo purposes*/
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

img:hover{
  transform:scale(1.8);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/60/40" alt=""/>
```

For vendor prefixes/compatibility, please click [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: great work!! thankx a lot.it's flying out on right side a bit. Actually i just want it up,but not right side.can you please help for that?

Comment: @ShahriarMd.Shoyeb: see now. (I altered for the scale origin to be at the bottom center)

Comment: If you wanted to add a shadow effect, you could [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26757893/3436942) from one of my previous questions/answers

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$('.flyout').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).animate({
        bottom: '0px'
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
.flyout{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -70px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

For hiding it again on scrolling:

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(){ 
    $('.flyout').animate({
         bottom: '-70px';
    });
});
```